# Python - Validating Phone Number before returning

Tags: python, regex

Considering the datasource I'm using is very dirty and can contain some of the following in the "phone number" fields;

- empty (New Standard)
- !! CLOSED !!
- none

I am doing a mass import and want to be sure to just not even bother with these. So I'm filtering through a class to format the numbers, but I also want to validate and just throw it away if it is not a number.

```
class PhoneNumber:
        def __init__( self, number_raw ):
                number = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', number_raw)
                self.area_code= number[ 0:3 ]
                self.exchange = number[ 3:6 ]
                self.line = number[ 6:13 ]

        def __str__( self ):
                return "({0}) {1}-{2}".format( self.area_code, self.exchange, self.line )
```

A few things to consider:

- I cannot modify the actual data source
- I cannot validate prior to reaching this class

I figure I could do something like this, and just use an if statement to pass `False` if its not a valid number, but I feel this could be sloppy.

What's a better way to validate that it is solely digits coming in, and if a string comes in just throw it out & return `None`?

---

**Potential Solution 1:**

```
class PhoneNumber:
        def __init__( self, number_raw ):
                validation = re.match('[^0-9]', '', number_raw)
                if validation is False:
                    return None
                else:
                    number = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', number_raw)
                    self.area_code= number[ 0:3 ]
                    self.exchange = number[ 3:6 ]
                    self.line = number[ 6:13 ]
                    self.full_number = number

        def __str__( self ):
                return "({0}) {1}-{2}".format( self.area_code, self.exchange, self.line )
```

**Potential Soluton 2:**

```
class PhoneNumber:
        def __init__( self, number_raw ):
            number = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', number_raw)
            self.area_code = number[ 0:3 ]
            self.exchange = number[ 3:6 ]
            self.line = number[ 6:13 ]
            self.og_number = number_raw

        def __str__( self ):
                validation = re.match('[^0-9]', '', self.og_number)
                if validation is False:
                    return None
                return "({0}) {1}-{2}".format( self.area_code, self.exchange, self.line )
```

Comment: when you say you want to "throw it away", do you want to just use None for the resulting number, or do you want to skip the entire record?

Comment: Maybe raise an exception on `__init__` if phone does not match pattern. Then simply catch it on `PhoneNumber` instantiation.

Comment: @ChrisCurvey I'd want to return None.

Comment: @needtobe hmm, that's a good idea, but my main concern is (being very novice yet) understanding where in this class I should do so to be most comprehensive. For instance, I'm not sure if it'd be better to catch on instantiation or when `__str__` is called.

Comment: Could you just try and cast it to an int?

Comment: @Adam I could and had this thought as well, but then I'd need to catch the TypeError which still leaves me in the same situation.

Comment: Catching it on `__str__` would be a mistake. You want to set each field to `None` (`areaCode`, `exchange`, `line`) if not valid? Plase don't do it. There is no reason to instantiate `PhoneNumber` of if it's not valid. I would stick with my first comment.

Comment: I don't disagree, I'm asking for an example as I'm not clear on direction from your first comment. Would you say catch it as the very first action in `__init__` ?

Comment: @CodeSpent Added an answer, you may look there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to instantiate an object with all fields set to None.
I would do some checks on `__init__` like so:

```
class PhoneNumber:
    def __init__(self, number_raw):
        number = int(number_raw)  # do not catch exception here, catch it on instantiation
        number_str = str(number)  # parse to str for slicing

        self.areaCode = number_str[0:3]  # note no space around slicing indexes
        self.exchange = number_str[3:6]
        self.line = number_str[6:13]
```

Also, worth noting would be using PEP-8-like variables, so use
`area_code` instead of `areaCode`.

**Second way (using classmethod)**

If you need to return `None` for some reasons, you may find useful instantiating using classmethod, like so:

```
class PhoneNumber:
    def __init__(self, number_raw):
        self.areaCode = number_raw[0:3] 
        self.exchange = number_raw[3:6]
        self.line = number_raw[6:13]

    @classmethod
    def instantiate_with_checks(cls, number_raw):
        try:
            int(number_raw)
        except ValueError:
            return None
        # after ensuring that provided variable is valid
        return cls(number_raw)
```

Instantiate new `PhoneNumber` object  like this:
`PhoneNumber.instantiate_with_checks(number_raw)`.

**Third way (using `__new__`):**

```
class PhoneNumber:
    def __init__( self, number_raw ):
        self.area_code = number[0:3]
        self.exchange = number[3:6]
        self.line = number[6:13]

    @classmethod
    def is_number_valid(cls, number_raw):
        try:
            int(number_raw)
        except ValueError:
            return False
        return True

    def __new__(cls, number_raw):
        if cls.is_number_valid(number_raw):
            return super().__new__(cls)
```

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at my Potential Solution in my edit & compared to your strategy, which seems more efficient & why?

Comment: You 're instantiating useless object there. Returning `None` in `__init__` does nothing at all, in fact this is a default behaviour.

Comment: Another thing to mention regarding PEP8 is that spaces are not placed immediately after or before parentheses.

Comment: @PMende Yes, added comment to emphasize it.

Comment: @PMende Also, I don't think using `regex` in that way would be a benefit for you. For example, for an input: `+444545454test34' you would get `44454545434`. Is that desired behaviour?

Comment: @PMende that's a weird aftermath of an extension I use for Django templates thinking it belongs there haha. So this won't help as I still don't have any control prior to this class (I don't instantiate). This is a once off script just for fixing formatting. Is matching at `__str__` really that detrimental?

Comment: @CodeSpent I'm a bit confused. Why would you create an object with all fields set to null?  In my opinion that's a bit bizzare. There should be no formatting if phone number is invalid, thus no object instantiated.

Comment: I am not. The current script says `if phone_number not None:` create the object. So this would mean an object would be "thrown away" if it received `None`. The only thing I can touch is where this class resides & beyond, not that script (access issue that could take weeks to resolve..). So my idea was if I match that what's coming in is not a number & not one of those anomolies, and return `None` for all those, then they'd never be created in the application at all. Does that make a bit better sense? Hacky, I know, but lesser of 2 evils.

Comment: Yes, that makes a sense, but if I understand correctly and `phone_number` is instantiation of `PhoneNumber` class, phone_number will never be `None`.

Comment: You may use `__new__` method or `classmethod` to achieve this. I will shortly update my answer.

Comment: Let me clarify that `phone_number` in my above comment is totally generic, sorry for the confusion. In most cases it will be `fire_line`, `burglar_line`, etc. So `if fire_line not None:`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189156/discussion-between-needtobe-and-codespent).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just do the formatting in the **init** and make your decision there as to whether you have a valid number or not?

```
class FormattedPhoneNumber(object):
  def __init__(self, number):
    try:
      as_number = int(number)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
      self._formatted = None
    else:
      # you have a number, do whatever formatting you need to do
      area_code = number[ 0:3 ]
      exchange = number[ 3:6 ]
      line = number[ 6:13 ]
      self._formatted = "({0}) {1}-{2}".format(area_code,exchange,line)

  def __str__(self):
    return self._formatted
```

Comment: Maybe using just `int(number)` instead of `as_number = int(number)` would be better? Int version is unnecessary.